# eks error : certificate-authority-data and certificate-authority are both specified for kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, ca, amazon-eks

I have a EKS setup ( kubernetes) with config file :

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: REDACTED
    server: https://E3D13176159D2CA5C51AF0622AFE252C.yl4.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: aws
  name: aws
current-context: aws
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: aws
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      args:
      - token
      - -i
      - terraform-eks-demo-green
      command: aws-iam-authenticator
      env: null
```

**the certificate-authority-data here is self signed (comes with EKS AMI)** , I am trying to set up a private docker registry for kubernetes (artifactory) which is https and uses internal cert.

so while applying my container I do the following :

```
kubectl apply  --certificate-authority='internal-ca.pem' -f echo-service.yaml
```

which fails with :

> error: certificate-authority-data and certificate-authority are both
>   specified for kubernetes. certificate-authority-data will override.

How do I setup a container to use the different ca cert other than the one defined in docker config ?

Currently any applying of container fails with :

> x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

because its using the former cert..

Answer (score 0):

The `kubectl` certificate authority option is for the client itself. What you want is set up the ca inside the container. There's a couple of ways I think you can setup (not limited):

1. Create a ConfigMap (or k8s secret) with the ca content and mount on your pod, and have your application reference it as the ca config (your docker registry)
2. Bake the config directly into the container in some `/etc/registry` directory for example and have your application reference it. The more recommended way is 1. due to the fact that it's generally not advisable to hard-cde cred stuff in your container image.

Comment: I have a secret for docker username and password in the yaml already which then I apply with kubectl. Is there a specific way to mount the CA in the yaml ?

Comment: That's already `certificate-authority-data` in your config. So that you can connect to the api server. Do you need a CA for your docker registry? do you want to sue the same? or a different one?

Comment: yup, trying to use CA for docker registry which is different than certificate-authority-data

Comment: use a ConfigMap or a Kubernetes secret

Comment: I get that but under what keyword should I put that in my yaml file ?

Comment: you mean yaml for your k8s deployment?

Comment: You can check this: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/